# How to disallow re-selecting image if already selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a click counter of images. There are multiple images and on clicking them, a counter on top of the page increments by 1.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Space Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" onClick="onClick()">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" onClick="onClick()">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" onClick="onClick()">
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body></html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QH5Vc/

How can I  make it like once an image has been clicked, you cannot click it again to re-increment the value? Like, if the first image is clicked and value goes from 0 to 1, when you re-click the first image, it will decrement the value whereas clicking any other than the first will increment.

Thanks!

Comment: you can add a class to each clicked image and then check if clicked image have that class, if it have, then do not increase clicks. But it easily hackable via inspector because you can remove this class from element and continue clicking.

Comment: @Quest - I don't want it to be hackable. Any other way?

Comment: The only other way would be to check it on server side, unfortunatelly.

Comment: how to do that? enlighten me

Comment: @Quest: The client side is always "hackable" (manipulable by the user). I don't think the OP cares about this, as the clicks aren't measured at the server anyway.